# iOS: iterating this json file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I have problems when parsing this JSON string.
Is there any difference of the approach when parsing a JSON string of this character, and one without the beginning and ending brackets?

The JSON looks like this.

```
    [
    {
        "id": 66,
        "username": "simon"
    },
    {
        "id": 69,
        "username": "simon"
    },
    {
        "id": 70,
        "username": "simon"
    },
    {
        "id": 71,
        "username": "simon"
    }
]
```

**My Code:**

```
    -(void)searchUserNamed:(NSString *)userID andAddTo:(UITableView*)tableView andAddUsersTo:(NSMutableArray*)users
    {     
        NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"token"];
        NSNumber *own_id = @([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"id"]);
        NSMutableDictionary *HTTPPostDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   userID, @"username",
                                                   token, @"token",
                                                   own_id, @"user_id",
                                                   nil];
        [[WebAPI sharedInstance] commandWithParams:HTTPPostDictionary command:@"search_user" onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){

                    for(NSDictionary *username in json){
                        NSLog(@"username: %@ FOUND", username);
                        [users addObject:username];
                        }
                    [tableView reloadData];
        }];
    }

**Which utilizes**

    -(void)commandWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)params command:(NSString *)command onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock
    {

        NSString *_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.baseURL, command];
        NSLog(@"path: %@", _path );

        NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"token"];
        NSNumber *userID = @([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"id"]);
        if(userID)[params setObject:userID forKey:@"user_id"];
        if(token)[params setObject:token forKey:@"token"];
            NSLog(@"%@",params);
        NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
        [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                        path:_path
                                  parameters:params
                   constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
                       //TODO: attach file if needed
                   }];


        AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            //success!

            NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
            if([responseObject objectForKey:@"status"] && ![[responseObject objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ok"] )
                ;
            else {
                NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
                completionBlock(responseObject);
            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            //failure :(
            completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"ERROR"]);
            // Unable to establish a connection to the server.
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server error"
                                                            message:@"Please try again later"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }];

       [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
    }
```

Comment: Give your code that you tried.

Comment: It's an Array of Dictionaries, not the JSON Repsonse. Show us the Parsing Code.

Comment: This looks like log of an array of dictionaries. This is not the actual JSON.

Comment: It is not a log either, those use semicolons

Comment: There is no difference at all between JSON with and without "those parentheses" because both are equally invalid.

Comment: Sorry. See my edit. The last section is the actual JSON, The other was console output.

Comment: These `[` `]` are brackets.  *These* `(` `)` are parentheses.  The distinction is important as far as JSON is concerned because the former are part of the syntax and the latter are not.

Comment: @Eyeball - have your problem been solved...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
    {
        "id": 66,
        "username": "simon"
    },
    {
        "id": 69,
        "username": "simon"
    },
    {
        "id": 70,
        "username": "simon"
    },
    {
        "id": 71,
        "username": "simon"
    }
]
```

The difference between this JSON and the above JSON without the **brackets** is that the above JSON is valid, and without brackets it is invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

**In ViewController.h**

```cs
    NSString *idStr;
    NSString * usernameStr;
    NSMutableArray *dataSourceArray;
    NSMutableDictionary *MutableDictionry;
```

**In ViewController.m**

```cs
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    dataSourceArray =[NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray *array;//this array will contain your json
    dataSourceArray = [self usersFromArray:array];        
 }
- (NSMutableArray *)usersFromArray:(NSArray *)array
 {
     NSMutableArray *users = [NSMutableArray array];
     for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
if (dict)
       {
              idStr = dict[@"id"];
              usernameStr = dict[@"username"];
        MutableDictionry=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:idStr,@"id",usernameStr,@"username",nil];

       }
    [users addObject:MutableDictionry];
 }
return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(NSDictionary *username in json)
```

json is `NSDictionary` but your json result is array,to change json as `NSMutableArray`

my suggestion to you,with out using for loop add objets to use  **addObjectsFromArray:** like this

```
[user addObjectsFromArray:json];//change json is an array
```